# Django datatime field

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm reading the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html) and I see that Postgres does not have a `datatime` data type but when I run `./manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 0001_initial` [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) actually generates a `datetime` field:

```
CREATE TABLE "myapp_event" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "start" datetime NOT NULL);
```

So I'm a bit confused. Is `datetime` suppose to be `timestamp`?

UPDATE:
I didn't realize I was using a different setting file with SQLite database. Hope this mistake may be useful to someone else.

In PostgreSQL it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "myapp_event" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "start" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL);
```

So `datetime` in SQLite is `timestamp with time zone` in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres does not have datetime data type indeed. Neither it has `AUTOINCREMENT` attribute. Django must be showing you those itself, translating Pstgres `timestamp` to `datetime` and `SERIAL` to `AUTOINCREMENT`.

PS `SERIAL` is not a datatype itself either.

here's I change your statement to Postgres one:

```
t=# CREATE TABLE "myapp_event" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "start" datetime NOT NULL);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTOINCREMENT"
LINE 1: ... "myapp_event" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREM...
                                                             ^
t=# CREATE TABLE "myapp_event" ("id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, "start" datetime NOT NULL);
ERROR:  type "datetime" does not exist
LINE 1: ...E "myapp_event" ("id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, "start" datetime N...
                                                             ^
t=# CREATE TABLE "myapp_event" ("id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, "start" timestamp NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
```

Comment: my version is 9.6 I ran statements with `psql`

Comment: no worries. lets just sweep up comments as they are irrelevant :)